# Delete operation does not perform in JS - PYTHON - POSTGRESS

Tags: javascript, http-status-code-500

**Controller:**

```
**@test_ref_bp.route('/cmds', methods=['GET', 'POST', 'PUT','DELETE'])
@swag_from('test_ref_doc.yml')
def testcommands():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        result, status = TestRefSvc.get_cli_commands()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        uploaded_file = request.files['file']
        if uploaded_file.filename != '':
            uploaded_file.save(uploaded_file.filename)
            result, status =  TestRefSvc.import_cli_commands(uploaded_file.filename)
        else:
            result, status =  [], 404
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        result, status = TestRefSvc.update_cli_commands(request.get_json())
    if request.method == 'DELETE':
        result, status = TestRefSvc.delete_cli_commands(request.get_json())
    return make_response(jsonify(result), status)**
```

**Service:**

```
**def delete_cli_commands(cli_commands_obj):
    commands_rs = TblCliCmds.query.get(cli_commands_obj['id'])
    print('The Delete query is ::: ',commands_rs)
    if not commands_rs:
        return {'error': 'Resource not found'}, 404
    db.session.delete(commands_rs)
    db.session.commit()
    return {'success': 'Resource deleted successfully'}, 204**
```

**Controller.js:**

```
**$scope.deleteCommandsData = function() {
        var dataset = {
            "id":$scope.loadCommandsData
        }
        console.log(dataset);
        alert(dataset.id);
        var api_url = $rootScope.base_url + $scope.app_route + "/cmds";
        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
        $http.delete(api_url, dataset, config)
        .then(function (status) {
            alert('Deleted successfully');
        });
    }**
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOTE9.jpg)

By calling delete operation, I have received the CORS origin error and tried all the possible ways to figure it out the issues. Is there any mistakes in the controller or JS or service layer.

Comment: Please use plain text in this topic, not images somewhere else.

Comment: Please edit your question to include a code block in body of question instead of a screenshot. [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: The image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOTE9.jpg shows that the response is a 500 error. That’s the root problem. The CORS message is just a side effect.

Comment: **$scope.deleteCommandsData = function() {
        var dataset = {
            "id":$scope.loadCommandsData
        }
        console.log(dataset);
        alert(dataset.id);
        var api_url = $rootScope.base_url + $scope.app_route + "/cmds/" +dataset.id;
        var config = {
            headers : {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
        $http.delete(api_url, dataset, config)
        .then(function (status) {
            alert('Deleted successfully');
        });
    }*